# jQuery, Only Trigger "Click" after "Blur" Has Fully executed

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I have an input element with a blur event, and a link element with a click event.  The problem I am running into is when someone clicks on the link element (the click), focus is taken off of the input element (the blur), but the simultaneous events cause the blur event to not fully execute.

What is the best way for making sure the blur event fully executes prior to firing the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way of handling it, but it should work... you can try putting a short `delay()` on the `click()` event.

My other thoughts are that you could try calling your `click()` handler from the callback of the `blur()`, but I'd have to tinker around with that to see how that'd work in practice.

Comment: to my knowledge there is no delay() method in javascript ;)

Comment: To my knowledge delay works on the jquery effects queue and have nothing whatsoever to do with events, but i might have missed something, and if thats the case, i apologize :)

Comment: I was thinking he'd put the delay inside the click handler he binds to his element via jQuery.  Again, this is a bit of a kludge, as he's basically got to hope that his 'short' delay is long enough for the blur to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as it turns out, the simultaneous events were not actually not what was causing my problem.  But I can see how your solution would help.  Calling the click() handler from the blur() event seems interesting and I'll play around with that if I should come across this issue again...

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the click event on the link and call input.blur() inside that event handler.

On 2nd thought, if the blur doesn't execute because the link click loads a new page, then you probably need to hook into unload or beforeunload events

Comment: That's a decent idea, too.  However, you might run into a problem there in knowing what input used to have focus.